# Are Jinmeiyō kanji part of the Hyōgai kanji?

Tags: jōyō-kanji

This question arised as part of the discussion [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83956/how-many-shinjitai-and-ky%c5%abjitai-characters-are-there/86778#comment141558_86778).

At first (see entry 1. [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%A8%E5%A4%96%E5%AD%97)) I thought that 表外{ひょうがい} (hyōgai) was a label for any kanji that is outside the 常用{じょうよう} (jōyō) list. However, in [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hy%C5%8Dgai_kanji) Wikipedia article they suggest that hyōgai does not include 人名用{じんめいよう} (jinmeiyō) kanji either. Which is the case? Maybe there is no unique, exact definiton of hyōgai?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your first link leads to Aidin Azari's profile, and not to a discussion.

Comment: @JansthcirlU fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term 表外漢字 has somewhat different usage in technical sense and everyday parlage.

Strictly speaking, there are 1'022 official 表外漢字. They are those designated by the National Language Council of Japan (国語審議会) in year 2000, delineated in this table: [1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Uncommon_kanji) (see also [2](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A1%A8%E5%A4%96%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E5%AD%97%E4%BD%93%E8%A1%A8%E3%81%AE%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7); source: [3](https://web.archive.org/web/20180429104139/https://www.mext.go.jp/b_menu/shingi/old_bunka/kokugo_index/toushin/1325296.htm)).

As it is easy to observe, some of these are even 常用, to say nothing of 人名用. But this is obviously by design, as these 常用 and 人名用 characters (such as 挨  for 常用 and 葦 for 人名用) were added to the corresponding lists later, after being highlighted for the 表外漢字 list before. In total, out of 1'022 characters, 151 went into 常用 wholesale:

> 挨宛闇椅畏萎咽臼怨岡臆俺苛崖蓋骸柿顎瓦韓玩畿巾串窟稽詣桁舷股乞勾喉頃痕挫塞阪埼柵拶斬嫉腫呪蹴拭尻芯腎裾凄醒戚脊羨腺膳狙捉袖唾堆戴誰綻酎潰爪諦貼妬栃頓鍋匂捻罵斑氾汎膝肘阜蜂貌勃昧枕蜜冥妖沃侶賂弄麓脇丼傲刹哺喩嗅毀彙恣惧慄拉曖鬱璧瘍箋籠緻羞訃諧貪踪辣淫葛僅煎詮遡遜捗溺塡賭謎剝箸蔽頰餅嘲茨牙餌蔑摯隙鍵梗釜

357 were borrowed for 人名用:

> 葦斡或粟庵按鞍夷謂蔭烏鵜窺碓姥瓜閏云曳榎堰奄燕甥荻桶牡珂蝦嘩俄峨臥駕芥蟹鎧笠樫梶恰兜蒲鴨萱粥柑竿雁掬杵鋸蕎禽寓釧沓窪隈鍬戟訣喧牽硯乎糊袴跨醐庚杭腔膏閤劫壕轟忽惚此昏些坐犀砦堺肴鷺窄晒撒珊纂讃仔斯獅而竺雫悉篠柴縞錫惹蒐輯嘗湘裳埴燭壬諏厨錐菅頗雀棲栖蹟尖閃曾楚疏蘇叢宋槍漕其舵楕陀苔醍托茸凧竪坦湛耽弛馳筑喋寵帖牒佃柘綴梯蹄釘鼎纏砥套宕撞萄鳶沌薙馴汝賑廿濡播杷琶芭煤柏箔曝莫函筈幡畠磐蕃庇枇毘琵疋菱畢紐瓢撫葡蕪葺淵吻焚頁圃戊菩捧鋒卜殆幌俣沫蔓箕湊蓑牟姪蒙勿尤貰輿傭淀螺洛裡掠劉溜梁淋鱗憐魯櫓狼肋鷲詫藁蕨椀碗凰巫已檜橙櫂渾煌絆蕾逞釉溢鰯迂噂焰襖鷗迦晦鞄徽祇俠卿喰櫛屑祁繫倦捲諺巷榊薩錆灼繡哨蔣醬鞘逗摺蟬撰噌辿樽簞註槌摑鄭擢顚堵禱灘楢禰這秤挽樋廟瀕瞥娩蓬鱒儲萊漣煉蠟汲饗穿揃篇迄逢辻楯廻俱訊瘦歎兎吞豹笈簾恢灸厩叉杖挺遁斧鞭籾

and only 514 were not used to supplement the main list (as of yet). Among those, 14 are traditional forms of simplified characters:

> 儘壺攪檮濤灌藪蠣諫賤邇頸鰺鶯

the rest are not:

> 虻鰻嬰洩穎厭蛾咳蛙廓橿鰹姦桓澗癌贋妓蟻吃仇渠僑怯狗珪畦荊姑狐菰垢糠濠漉鮭捌屍痔綬讐鋤妾娼鉦鍾擾疹塵笥趨脆鼠鐸叩狸蛋蜘諜銚吊剃碇轍澱淘蕩禿苫韮葱撚膿覗蚤狽粕筏噺蛤髭蛭鮒扮糞僻呆鉾吠鵡牝悶涌熔燐牢聾歪鰐乖于亢仄佇侘俤俯偈冑几剋匈卉曼吼呵咎呟呻咄咸咤哭啜啖唸喀喘啼嗚嗟嗜嘔嘴嚥囁囃址埃埒墟壙奢奸娑婉娶媚嬌孕孵宦宸寥尹屁屎屹峙崗嵌帚帛帷幟廂廬彎彷徊恍悍悸愕憚憑憫罹懺懼戌截戮抉抒拗拿拮捏掟揆揉揶揄撥攀攘攣敲斃旱晰暈曠曰朦朧杣枡柩梵棘椒棹楔楮楡槃榜榴檻櫃櫟欅殷毫毯沁泄洒浙涅涵涸滓漑漿滲瀑濾瀾炒炬炸焉熾燵爛爬猥瑕疆疇疵疽疸疱痒痙痰痺瘡瘤瘻癬皺盂眩睨睫睾瞑瞞瞰瞼砒磋礫祀祠祟祓禊穢窩竦箒箏篆簀籬紮絨絣綽罠翅翳耆聊聘聚聳肛胚胱脛腋隋脾腑膀膠膣膵臀臂臍臘舅舐芻苞茫莢荼萼蓼薨蕭薔薇蘆蛉蛛蜀蜻蝸雖蟇衙袁袂袢裔褌褥襞襦襷訛訶誅誦諤諱謔諷謗謳譚賽贄贅趙趾跏跋踵蹊躁躇躊躬軋轢逍遽邁邱鄙鈔鉗鉤鋏鍼閨閻閾闊闍陝隕隧雉霰靄勒鞋韋竟頷頽顆飫饉饅饒髷髻鬘鬚鬢魏鮨鰓鰊鸚鸞靡齟齬啞飴嚙翰翫軀鹼麴鵠鯖屢杓酋薯藷蝕搔驒腿蛸瀦鎚屠瀆瀞囊牌潑醱稗逼謬庖麵鑓愈榔冤屛攢噓餐煽箭叛扁篝騙﨟鄧誹徘靱猷叟囀艘鴉姸幷疼筵甕訝粂虔腱咬狡鮫甦甑竈駁芒爺蠅蜃

In everyday usage, however, the term 表外漢字 refers to any kanji "outside (外) some list (表)." It may refer to non-常用, to non-当用, non-(常用+人名用) characters based on context. However, most typically this covers both the 常用 and 人名用 lists together.

Note that 外字 is a somewhat different concept, referring to characters not covered by some electronic character set (such as JIS X 0208) or a specific font and thus requiring to use hacks instead of just coding the characters.

Comment: It's so weird that these kanji categories are defined by lists, rather than by the more accommodating everyday descriptions you mentioned near the end of your answer.